# connecting to hive to execute queries wih kerberos

Tags: hive, client, kerberos

I am trying to connect to hive databases with a client, I have tried using DBeaver and downloaded the hive driver, but after that I have noticed that there is a kerbero's instance in the middle, and it seems that the dbeaver driver doesn't supoort kerberos.

¿There is some windows client suitable to query hive databases easy to plug in, considering the kerbero's instance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no easy way to combine Java, Kerberos, Hadoop and Windows. Avoid the Apache JDBC driver which has nasty dependencies on the Hadoop "native" libraries _(with no official Windows build)_ and use the Cloudera driver, based on commercial Simba SDK (and it's a a proper Type 4 driver, too)

Comment: Whether you use DBeaver or DBVisualizer, the tool itself does not care about Kerberos. The Hive driver does. Either you have a valid Java-and-Linux-style-Kerberos-ticket available, or you must force a JAAS config file via Java system properties _(to use a specific principal/keytab, or to use the Windows creds with Single-Sign-On)_ in the tool's command line, and JAAS conf is black magic.